# Run the TraceBuilder for converting JobHistory file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to convert jobhistory file with Hadoop tool Rumen for my YARN SLS learning. I cannot run the tracebuilder command. I found nothing for the problem on internet. I found nothing for this problem on internet. I want to know how to solve it, thank you. 
There are INFOs:

```
$ hadoop rumentrace 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.TraceBuilder$MyOptions.<init>(TraceBuilder.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.TraceBuilder.run(TraceBuilder.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.TraceBuilder.main(TraceBuilder.java:186
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the command is trying to parse cli options, and you gave it **none**

It requires at least 3 args

```
hadoop rumentrace [options] <jobtrace-output> <topology-output> <inputs>
```

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-rumen/Rumen.html

Comment: Your meaning is that my rumen tool is ok. But it runs none because my file has error.

Comment: What file? You're not giving any arguments, so you get out of bounds

Comment: I understand. Thank you. Must this input file be a jobhostory file generated by hadoop? I want to use the Google cluster data to try scheduler but that file format is .csv.

Comment: Google Dataproc is still running Hadoop

Comment: Google cluster data is it. https://github.com/google/cluster-data   I want to use the data for my YARN scheduler learning with SLS. Please tell me how can I use this data. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, but assuming you're using GCP, I would not use Hadoop there. I would put the file in GCS, then use BigQuery to query the CSV. If you're doing things locally, you could use Apache Hive or Drill for similar SQL purposes

Comment: Thank you so much. You solve an important problem for me... I searched many websites but I never found answer.